# page.php dependent sites are not working in custom woocommerce theme

Tags: theme-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I simply want to add woocommerce to a very lite, selfmade wp-theme.
Therefore I followed the guide provided on the [woocommerce website](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/).

I actually reduced the `page.php` to

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php woocommerce_content(); ?>
<?php get_footer();
```

and also tried to change its name to `woocommerce.php`.

But, in neither case I could reproduce the effect I observed with the same changes in standard wp-themes (as twentyseventeen), which was a default output of the page.php dependent woocommerce pages as checkout, cart, account.

If I add html content, this will be displayed on the corresponding woocommerce page. Only the woocommerce content is missing.

The shop page, as well as the single product pages work fine. So what could be wrong with the cart, etc.?

Thanks in advance for any advice.